# Desktop remains on, display quits working, loud "skipping" noise follows

Tags: cpu, hardware-failure, shutdown, gpu

For the past 2-3 days, strange things have been going on with my desktop and its interaction with the monitor. While playing a game, my monitor went black as if my computer had been shut off. However, the computer remained on. Power was still active, every fan inside of the case was working, etc.

Originally, I thought it was just an incompatibility with this game, but then it happened again while watching YouTube. The screen goes black and there is an audible "skipping" sound, one you might expect to hear when a physical CD of music is dirty and stops mid-track.

At this time, I'm thinking it has to do with my video card. I didn't recently install any new drivers or anything. I play a game again, wait for this to happen, and ensure that my video card's fan is still working when this happens again. It is. I check the temperatures of my GPU, CPU, etc. All is well. I even clean out my case. Still, this continues to happen.

At this time, I'm thinking maybe it's the hard drive. I run health tests, etc. I run an error repair in Windows (as I'm running 8.1). Everything seems fine. I guess all that's left is the power supply? Could it be something to do with that? I am stumped and clueless at this point.

Other things I'll note:

- No new software or drivers were recently installed.
- I've run a long GPU stress test with FurMark, and it went smoothly. No issues.
- I've run a long CPU stress test. It went fine.
- I've inspected the case when this "shut off" occurs. Nothing visibly stops working.

It confuses me that I can get this problem to occur during a YouTube or gaming session, but during FurMark's most stressful benchmarking test, it works like a charm. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you also apply the furmarks artifact scanning too, as it tests hard the video memory, which many of the demos and GPU testing does not.  http://superuser.com/questions/781473/catalyst-control-center-stops-working-when-graphic-card-is-being-used/781494#781494  <-- there is a big long diatribe I wrote on GPU recover issues. (recover being when the gpu fails and resets).  You are saying that it NEVER comes back from this fail? that the built in recovery for a gpu fail never occurs and your always left with a black screen?

Comment: SMART tool and update your drivers

Comment: Check your video card and RAM first.

Comment: @Psycogeek It never comes back from this fail, I have to shut the computer down by the power button.

Comment: Although it doesn't particularly sound like a hard drive issue to me, seconding @DaveRook's suggestion of a quick SMART diagnostic. It's an easy test to rule out your hard drive and give you some piece of mind.  [CrystalDiskInfo](http://crystalmark.info/software/CrystalDiskInfo/index-e.html) is a good tool for the job.

Comment: Also is there anything interesting in the Windows' event logs?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a failing hard drive to me. Check your drive's S.M.A.R.T. data with a tool like smartmon. The windows install instructions are available [here](http://www.smartmontools.org/wiki/Download#InstalltheWindowspackage).

I believe this is the case based on the sounds you're reporting, but I would imagine that Windows would give a blue screen or restart itself in that case.

You say you ran 'health tests' but depending on which program you used that information can be misleading. If a drive runs fine and continues to read and write, then by all means on a cursory inspection it is indeed 'healthy' or 'works fine'. You want to read the drives' raw SMART logging data and look at the reallocated sectors and pending sectors. These indicate that hard drive media is failing or the i/o heads are weak. This type of failure can cause errors but many HDD health programs will report that the drive is 'OK'.